# When logging in, screen flashes then kicks back to login screen - Cannot login even in Safe mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login, login-screen

I know this is similar to another post here but it went unanswered.
[Previous Thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123880/login-screen-flashes-and-returns-to-login-screen-tried-everything-possible)

I have a Late 2010 13" Macbook Air with Mavericks installed since launch.

I was trying to use an external monitor which was giving me fits.  I unplugged it and ended up getting logged out of my user account.  When logging back in my screen turned a bluish tint then flashed and returned to the login screen.  At the time I also had a keychain problem pop up which I was able to fix.  I have tried the suggestions on the other thread other than transferring the information to a new user account as this happened yesterday.

I need to know if anyone has found a fix for this as the previous poster hasn't returned to the thread.  This is my work computer so I need to salvage as much as possible and hopefully fix it completely.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you explain why is the solution in the http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123880/login-screen-flashes-and-returns-to-login-screen-tried-everything-possible not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the identical problem. There appears to be no solution other than to reinstall OSX from the ground up!

Comment: Did reinstalling fix it for you or have you not attempted your solution?